# mvc $('form').submit do not execute on partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am developing an MVC 5 App.

I have a `Parent View` that call a `Partial View` to change de Picture.

Here is my call to Partial View...

```
$('formPhoto').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert(1);
            },
            success: function(result) {
                successPhoto(result);
            },
            complete: function() {
                // alert(3);
                // And so on.
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

My Partial View looks like this

[image: My Partial View looks like this]

My Form is called "FormPhoto".
I defined a `Ajax` function on Submit like this.

```
$('formPhoto').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                alert(1);
            },
            success: function(result) {
                successPhoto(result);
            },
            complete: function() {
                // alert(3);
                // And so on.
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

This function is never executed on Submit.

What I am missing?

Also, I try to get Partial View data using

> var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));

But I think it is incorrect.

Any ideas?

Tahnks?

Comment: Never post code as image. Don't use snippets for code that doesn't run anyway; simply indent by 4 spaces to show code. Also: basic troubleshooting. Put `alert()`s in your code to make sure it is called at all. Re-read docs of stuff you're using (like jQuery).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a jquery **id** `selector`:

```
$('#formPhoto')
```

instead

```
$('formPhoto')
```

> Also, I try to get Partial View data using `var formdata = new FormData($(this).get(0));`

Here you create a `FormData` object which contains `form` details.

`var formdata = new FormData($(this)[0]);`- This will submit the form elements automatically in the `FormData` and you don't need to manually append the data to `FormData` variable.

Here is an example:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var formData=new FormData($('#myForm').get(0));
  console.log(formData.get('input1'));
  console.log(formData.get('input2'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" value="test" name="input1"/>
  <input type="text2" value="test2" name="input2"/>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```